# SSL certificate integration for S3 hosted website using GoDaddy hosted domain name

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3

My static website is hosted on Amazon S3, and my domain name is hosted on GoDaddy.  I have added MX records from Route53.  I want to know how to add SSL to this static site.

Comment: [GoDaddy provides SSL certificates](https://www.godaddy.com/web-security/ssl-certificate) for an added price.

Comment: yes we have that we need to create csr from hosting provider

Comment: Related: [Serving a Static Site Over HTTPS Using S3, CloudFront, and GoDaddy](https://medium.com/@brodartec/hosting-a-static-site-with-https-enabled-using-aws-s3-cloudfront-and-godaddy-826dae41fdc6)